# How to tell the difference between Page Up and Down C++ Windows

Tags: c++, keyboard, windows-xp

I am trying to use Page Up and Page Down both in my C++ Windows XP project. I have run into a problem. Normally, I can tell if any key is pushed by using _Getch (from "conio.h") and then using the key's numerical ascii value to test the answer. It checks _Getch for a number that corresponds to the key. The problem is that Page Up and Page Down both share the same number, along with many other keys on that side of the keyboard. How can i tell the difference between the two? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `GetAsyncKeyState` (and please read the documentation on the return value first). I don't recommend `<conio.h>`.

Comment: are you sure it doesn't generate multiple bytes?

Comment: @Chris If you want to enter this as an answer, then please do so. Don't answer with a comment please! However, I will try using this instead. Please write an official answer.

Comment: @Evanias: for a long time i answered *only* in comments. it's better that way since comments are much less affected by voting (in particular, the person that in generally is least competent to select "the" solution doesn't get to select a comment), much more difficult to sabotage by adding comments, and much faster to write than a detailed answer. those who want quick answers should prefer to get their answers as comments, i think.

Comment: Looking up some documentation, here's what he's getting at: *When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code.* That's for `_getch`, but I didn't see any `_Getch`, so I presume you meant `_getch`. I also didn't realize this is local to the console, so probably better than `GetAsyncKeyState` for that purpose, which would otherwise turn into something like `ReadConsole`.